# How to deploy Qt apps developed in OS X to Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt

I have developed a Qt app on OS X (El Capitan) using Qt 5.5 framework and want to deploy my app to Windows. I came across [this](https://godhc.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/build-your-qt-project-on-windows-and-mac-osx/) article but I have a few questions;

1. MinGW compiler page linked in the article says it support unto Qt 4.8, but my project is developed using Qt 5.5, will it be a problem?
2. Moreover, as instructed by the article I could not find Qt 5.5 libraries for windows on Qt site; the link provided by the article seems broken.

Can you please give me a step by step process to deploy a static executable of my project from my Mac or link an article (I have searched online, but could not find any)? It is really disappointing since one of the major selling points of Qt is

> "code once, deploy anywhere"

But this very crucial step lacks proper documentation or guidance unlike Qt impressive mainstream documentation.

Comment: Why not try [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/download/) itself? Just download and install it, and you're good to go. If you are making that Qt project for fun, for open-source or for student use, it's free of charge and is a ready-made IDE for Qt projects that also has graphical interfaces. You can also install it on Mac, so you would have the same GUI for both operating systems. *(P.S. : Yes, I know, I'm dodging the questions)*

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator. I have made my project and want to deploy it now. Needing to install Qt creator in target machine to use this app, I believe, is not a elegant way to do things. But that will be my last resort though. Any advise on how to deploy exe app?

Comment: There's already various answered questions about deploying Qt applications on Windows. Qt 5.8 is available for MinGW, you can find the download page here: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw530-5.8.0.exe.mirrorlist

Comment: Qt is *source* compatible. You need to *build* your software from its source code on every platform you want to deploy it on. How you build your software (or Qt itself) is not the business of Qt.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Oh I get it now. Thank you for the insight. I am a newbie to software development (still learning), and my notion on Qt deployment was totally wrong. I thought you deploy a compiled project from a given OS anywhere.

Comment: Qt defines a source API (in C++). The C++11 standard defines a programming language. Hopefully, your *source* code, in C++11, using Qt5, when compiled & built, gives [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) which behave likewise on several platforms. But how you build your software is not the business of Qt, it is your own business. Read also about [Package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager). I never used Windows (I'm using Linux since 1993), but I heard that building software in Qt is harder on Windows than on Linux. But **it is*your* responsability**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @Massimo Callegari provided a resourceful answer, I did not use it achieve my task, probably because my project was massively complicated. Instead I came across [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows) wiki page instruction to deploy Windows Qt apps. It works like charm, and I though I should document it here since it would be really helpful to new learners just like me. My project uses  various 3rd party libraries like QCustomPlot, QXlsx. So the point I am implying is that the method described link regardless whether your project uses Qt native modules or 3rd party modules. But I presume this may not be the most elegant way to deploy an app (I think using installation packager along with installation softwares like InstallShield is the optimal solution) but nevertheless this method gets the job done. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My project is based on Qt and it is deployed on Linux, Windows and macOS.

On Windows I use [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) which includes the Qt libs (at the moment 5.6.2) and it is pretty awesome if your project has several external dependencies. I found that with the official Qt/MINGW environment, building external dependencies is kind of a hell.

Here's the wiki to instruct my users how to [build on Windows](https://github.com/mcallegari/qlcplus/wiki/Windows-Build-Qt5).

Once you have done make install, you need to copy the Qt libraries to the install folder, including all the QML deps (if you use any)

Then I use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) to actually create the final self installing EXE bundle. This is [the script](https://github.com/mcallegari/qlcplus/blob/master/platforms/windows/qlcplusQt5.nsi) I use in my project

Hope that helps.

Otherwise, I suggest you to read the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) if you haven't already

Comment: Hey bro thank you for your answer. I have installed MSYS2 by following  your instructions. Now foe the next part where you have told to copy the Qt libraries in the install folder, could you please elaborate with more details? Should I download Qt 5.5 libraries? How couldI do this? Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, the Qt libraries are included in MSYS2 (mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-qt5). It's 5.6.2, so it's a LTS version. You don't need to intall extra stuff.
To copy to the target folder, you need to prepare a .pro file dedicated to the cause. I have one for each platform. [Check this out](https://github.com/mcallegari/qlcplus/blob/master/platforms/windows/windows.pro).
Remember to include also the basic DLLs like libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

Comment: P.S. If my answer satisfies your needs, you should accept it.